What's the difference if subshell vs compound statements in if statement?
In bash script, I need to run a command, which is a && compound, I wonder what's the difference between put it in a subshell, and just run it in if condition?
if ! ( cmd_A && cmd_B ); then
    doSth
fi

vs.
if ! cmd_A && cmd_B; then
    doSth
fi


! always applies to exactly one pipeline. In your first example, that pipeline is the (...) command. In your second example, it's the first pipeline cmdA that constitutes the first part of the list defined by &&.
If you don't actually want a subshell, but still want to negate the exit status of cmdA && cmdB, use a command group:
if ! { cmdA && cmdB; }; then
    doSth
fi


Just learned about the command group, it looks nicer, thanks for the answer!

@fluter : yes, cmd groups are nice. Be sure to make it a habit to include the ; char before the closing }. Good luck.

Why? is there any difference with or without the ending ;?

} isn't special, except in command position. With { cmdA && cmdB }, } is just another argument to cmdB, and the command group started with { remains incomplete. The ; terminates the cmdB command, so that } is in command position, and so interpreted as the end of the current command group.

! will only invert one command.
The whole subshell is one command, but without the parentheses, cmd_A is one command and cmd_B is another.
However, your emphasis on a subshell is also likely confusing you.
{ cmd_A && cmd_B; } is also a single compound command, and not a subshell. ! { cmd_A && cmd_B; } would usually have a similar behavior to ! ( cmd_A && cmd_B ), at least as far as the exit status goes.
Other compound commands are available, starting with {, [[, ((, for, select, case, if, while, and until. So you can invert the result of an entire if expression, or for loop, if you want.

! inverts one pipeline, e.g. ! foo | bar negates the exit status of foo | bar, not just foo.
